# Vertically & horizontally centering a div with an image of variable size

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues centering a popup div with a variable height and width on screen. The idea is to use this for a simple photo gallery. I know that this question has been asked a million times, and I have been searching the web for this for half a day now, but most solutions do not seem to match my requirements (or just don't work)... Still, I have the terrible feeling that I'm missing something super-simple, but I can't seem to get it right today...

Requirements are as follows:

- The image should be displayed in the center of the screen, both horizontally and vertically.
- The image's aspect ratio should be preserved.
- If the image is larger
  than the min-width/min-height of its container, it should resize
  until it is 100% or until it matches either max-width/max-height of
  its container.
- The container div should fit around the image without added
  margins to make sure other control elements can be positioned
  correctly.
- Neither the size of the page nor the size of the images is known, and images can be portrait as well as landscape in orientation. Thus, it is not possible to set a fixed width/height.

The structure I've been using so far has made use of either a table or divs with display: table; or display: table-cell; to center the div that contains the image. This seems to work alright, but there might be a better solution...

However, I cannot get the image to reliably respect the max-width/max-height properties of the parent container. I suppose that this is because a width/height specification on the image doesn't really work if the container div does not have fixed dimensions. Is there a way around this?

To illustrate what I've been doing, I've created a simple breakdown that works on e.g. jsfiddle.net. Please don't pay too much attention to the cleanliness of the code (this is really just a simplified example to play with).

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay" class="overlay" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
  <table class="overlay">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="lightbox"><img id="photo" alt="Foto" src="http://placehold.it/1200x300"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('photo').src = 'http://placehold.it/1200x300';
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';">Very wide image.</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('photo').src = 'http://placehold.it/300x1200';
  document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';">Very tall image.</a>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow: scroll;
  display: none;
}

table.overlay {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}

table.overlay td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

div.lightbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

div.lightbox img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

In this example, the "very wide image" is displayed correctly, but the "very tall image" takes up more than 100% of the page height. This may obviously depend on your browser window dimensions, though, but I hope this illustrates my problem.

I've tried many different variations on this. Amongst other things, I tried playing with overflow, but this isn't an option because I want neither scrollbars nor clipping.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm missing?

One final thing: I don't mind using javascript, since the content will also be filled with javascript anyway. However, I would really prefer not to use jquery or another framework...

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help : https://jsfiddle.net/okzfr1cw/1/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I forgot to mention that I tried something similar as well. Although this works just fine to position the image, I ran into difficulties when I tried to place a container div around the image of the right size. Although I don't really need a container div, this was the only way I could think of to add controls to the image. But maybe you know of an alternative method that ties in to this way of positioning the image to e.g. position a close icon in the top-right corner of the image, and next/previous overlays left and right of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost certain you won't be able to solve this issue without using javascript.

The example below employs *unobtrusive javascript* and it is intended to be scalable:

```js
var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

function hideOverlay() {
document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';
}

overlay.addEventListener('click',hideOverlay,false);


var initiateDisplayImage = []

function displayImage(i) {

var photoSources = [
'http://placehold.it/1200x300',
'http://placehold.it/300x1200'
];

var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
overlay.style.display = 'block';

var photo = document.getElementById('photo');
photo.src = photoSources[i];

photo.style.width = '';
photo.style.height = '';

function photoDimensions() {
var photoWidth = photo.clientWidth;
var photoHeight = photo.clientHeight;
var photoRatio = photoWidth / photoHeight;

var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

if (photoWidth > windowWidth) {
photo.style.width = (windowWidth - 40)  + 'px';
photoWidth = photo.clientWidth;
photo.style.height = (photoWidth / photoRatio)  + 'px';
}

if (photoHeight > windowHeight) {
photo.style.height = (windowHeight - 40)  + 'px';
photoHeight = photo.clientHeight;
photo.style.width = (photoHeight * photoRatio)  + 'px';
}
}

photo.addEventListener('load',photoDimensions,false);

}


function initiateDisplayImageFunction(i) {
return function(){
var anchor = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i];
anchor.addEventListener('click',function(){displayImage(i);},false);};
}

function initiateDisplayImages() {
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
initiateDisplayImage[i] = initiateDisplayImageFunction(i);
initiateDisplayImage[i]();}
}

window.addEventListener('load',initiateDisplayImages,false);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  overflow: scroll;
  display: none;
}

table.overlay {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}

table.overlay td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid green;
}

div.lightbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

div.lightbox img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
  <table class="overlay">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="lightbox"><img id="photo" alt="Foto" src="http://placehold.it/1200x300"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<a href="#">Very wide image.</a>
<br>
<a href="#">Very tall image.</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I should be able to adapt this to fully suit my needs (including min/max dimensions, for example). However, I'm having an issue with the .currentWidth/.currentHeight properties. It seems that they are only set after the image has finished loading (which makes sense). Therefore, they are returning 0 for me, and the code fails to do anything. Is there any solution for this? I can think of adding an arbitrary time-out, but that seems like a very bad idea for a number of reasons... Thanks again! :)

Comment: I see what you mean. That's easily fixed! No need for an arbitrary time-out. All you need is to make sure the resizing _only_ happens after the image source has loaded... and for that all you need to do is wrap the resizing in a function and reference that function with the following event listener: `photo.addEventListener('load',photoDimensions,false);`. See the edits I've made to the post above.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reaction. I will try it out, and get back later. But it sounds like this should do the trick indeed. Thanks!

Comment: I have been busy, but I finally tested it, and it works well! I accepted your answer. Thanks again for the help!